# Why Git core.autocrlf doesn't work for me?

Tags: git

This is what I'm doing:

```
$ git init /tmp/repo
$ echo -e "1\r\n2" > x.txt
$ hexdump x.txt
0000000 31 0d 0a 32
$ git config --local core.autocrlf false
$ git add x.txt
$ git commit -m 'test' x.txt
[master (root-commit) fe8c018] x.txt
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 x.txt
```

As far as I understand, the file in the repo now is `1\r\n2`. Now, if I checkout this code, the content of the file should be `1\n2`, right? But it's not:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
$ git clone file:///tmp/repo r
$ cd r
$ hexdump x.txt
0000000 31 0d 0a 32
```

Why it's still `\r\n`? It's [supposed to be](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) `\n`, right?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.14.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we do is add a `.gitattributes` file in the root of our repo with the following:

```
* text eol=lf
*.ttf binary
*.woff binary
*.woff2 binary
```

The first line is a "catch all" that sets all line endings to Unix-style - you can omit the `eol` bit or set it to `crlf` instead. That should catch your .txt file.

Not that the `.gitattributes` will have priority over the single developer's git configuration on their machine, that's why it's advised to have one - especially if you work cross-platform.

This unfortunately has never worked, never figured out why: `* -text`

Answer (score 1):

I think git doesn't recognise this file as a text file and treat it as a binary. **autocrlf** doesn't effect binary files.

To mark specific file or extension as text you can add **.gitattributes** file where you specify witch files to treat as text, for example:

```
*.x text
```

Will tell git to treat all files with extension 'x' as text and apply **autocrlf**

Please refer for this documentation for [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

Comment: I did what you suggested, no effect.

Comment: `-text` **unsets** the `text` attribute.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski tnx, I have a different use case and blindly copied it from my file. Thank you for spotting it!

Comment: I am not sure my answer is super relevant anymore, as extension in question is 'txt' now. But maybe it will be useful for someone exploring area in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As git-config man page `core.autocrlf`option is used for convert 'LF' to 'CRLF'.

```
$ git init /tmp/repo
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/repo/.git/
$ cd /tmp/repo
$ echo -ne "1\n2" > x.txt
$ hexdump x.txt
0000000 31 0a 32
0000003
$ git config --local core.autocrlf false
$ git add x.txt
$ git commit -m 'test' x.txt
[master (root-commit) 7ed185b] test
1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 x.txt
$ cd ..
$ git config --global core.autocrlf true
$ git clone file:///tmp/repo r
Cloning into 'r'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
$ cd r
$ hexdump x.txt
0000000 31 0d 0a 32
0000004
```